# Is it possible to dynamically load new functions to a running C program?

Tags: c

Consider the following C program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

const int OP_0 = 0;
const int OP_1 = 1;
const int OP_2 = 2;

int op_0(int x) {
  return x + 2;
}

int op_1(int x) {
  return x * 3 + 1;
}

int op_2(int x) {
  return 2 * x * x - 10 * x + 5;
}

int compute(int op, int x) {
  switch (op) {
    case OP_0: return op_0(x);
    case OP_1: return op_1(x);
    case OP_2: return op_2(x);
  }
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  int opcode;
  int number;

  printf("Enter the opcode: ");
  scanf("%d", &opcode);

  printf("Enter the number: ");
  scanf("%d", &number);

  printf("Result: %d\n", compute(opcode, number));

  return 0;
}
```

It is a very simple program that lets the user select one of 3 operations to perform on an `int` input. To use this program, we can compile it with, for instance, `gcc program.c -o program`, and then run it with `./program`. That's all obvious. Suppose, though, that we wanted to add another operation:

```
int op_3(int x) {
  return 900 + x;
}
```

If we wanted to use this new operation, we'd need to **recompile** the entire program. Adding a new operation to this program has `O(n)` complexity, and is slow since it requires a complete recompilation.

**My question is: is it possible, in C, to let this program add new native operations (without writing an interpreter)? In other words, is it possible to dynamically compile and add op_3 to the C program above, without having to recompile everything?**

For illustration purposes, here is an example of what I have in mind:

```c
int compute(int op, int x) {
  // the first time it runs, would load `op_N.dll`
  // the next time, would use the loaded version
  // so, to add a new operation, we just compile
  // it and add `op_N.dll` to this directory
  Fun op = dynamic_load(op);
  return op(x);
}
```

Comment: On Unix you can use the dynamic linker functions: `dlopen()` and `dlsym()`.

Comment: This is the meaning of DLL acronym on Windows. On Unix you have shared libraries.

Comment: The topic is interesting, but the question is poorly asked. Loading code is not part of C (unlike  Java with its class loaders, which perhaps you are thinking of).  It's part of the operating system. Since you can use C to make the operating system do all possible tricks, sure it can be done of the OS can do it. But your question needs to specify the environment. As evidence, note that both linux dl and Windows dll functions have already been mentioned. Other environments may or may not have similar capabilities.

Comment: @Gene to ask a question perfectly one must already know the answer :P Thanks everyone who pointed me to the right direction. I've posted a complete solution below, in case anyone in a future asks this question with the same sub-optimal choice of words.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but a good question in SO describes the programming environment. You don't need to know the answer to provide that.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of is to compile a new dynamic library that is then opened by the program using `dlopen()`...

Another way, similar but perhaps more primitive, would be to compile the code into an object file and then load it into a mmaped region with execution permissions, jumping then to it using a function pointer.

To do this, compile the new function using `gcc -c`, clean the binary code from the headers with `objcopy -O binary -j .text`. Now in the program `open()` the resulting file and use the `mmap()` function to map this file in memory, giving as protections `PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC`. You'd look up the manuals for all this functions.

Note that I am assuming that you are on a unix system. I don't know much about Windows, but I imagine that something similar could be done with `VirtualAlloc()`.

Comment: Great answer! I like the second option, but I never heard of that. How do I "load an object file into a mmaped region with execution permissions"?

Comment: @MaiaVictor, I edited my answer to explain in more detail.

Comment: @MaiaVictor, just take into account that the "good" and "clean" way here would be to use a library, as everyone else is pointing out.

Comment: yes, I get it now. Very informative and helpful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you are asking is the "Open Principle of SOLID".  To do so, you need to have a dynamic `dlsym` obviously after `dlopen`.  To have a dynamic `dlsym` you need to be able to read header files or a file with the proper function prototypes. Yes, you need to cast function pointers, but the typecast depends upon the types of your parameter list.

Edit:
Hard coding `dlsym` means you have to relink your import library to your executable every time you add a function to your shared object.

OR

You have two shared objects. One is the import library, and the other is the library that you want to add functionality. As David Wheeler said, "All problems of computer science could be solved with another level of indirection, except for the problem with too many layers of indirection.".

Answer (score 0):

Complete noob-proof answer. As the other answers suggested, we can use `dlopen` and `dlsym` to dynamically load a shared library on C. First of all, let's create the lib. Save the following file as `0.c`

```c
int fn(int x) {
  return x * 10;
}
```

Then, run the following command to create the shared lib:

```c
clang -shared 0.c -o 0
```

Now, we must edit our `compute` function to load `fn` from `0.c` dynamically and use it. First, we declare an `fn : int -> int` function pointer:

```c
int (*fn)(int);
```

Then, we convert the operation to decimal (since we saved the shared lib as `0`, no extension):

```c
char file[256];
sprintf(file, "%d", 0);
```

Then, we load `0` dynamically:

```c
void *handle = dlopen(file, RTLD_LAZY);
```

Then, we find `fn` on that lib, and assing to the `fn` function pointer:

```c
*(void**)(&fn) = dlsym(LIB[op], "fn");
```

Then, we can just call it!

```c
fn(5) // will return 50
```

Here is a complete example, that handles errors and stores the function pointers in a jump table (so we don't need to re-load the lib every time, obviously!):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

const int MAX_OPS = 256;

// Jump-table with available functions
int (*OP[MAX_OPS])(int);

// Array with shared libraries
void* LIB[MAX_OPS];

// Loads an operation dynamically
void load_op(int op) {
  int (*fn)(int);

  // Generates the file name
  char file[256];
  sprintf(file, "%d", op);

  // Opens the dynamic lib
  LIB[op] = dlopen(file, RTLD_LAZY);

  // Handles error opening the lib
  if (!LIB[op]) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't load operation: %s\n", dlerror());
  }

  // Creates the function pointer
  *(void**)(&fn) = dlsym(LIB[op], "fn");

  // Handles error finding the function pointer
  if (!fn) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't load operation: %s\n", dlerror());
    dlclose(LIB[op]);
  }

  // Adds to jump table
  OP[op] = fn;
}

// Clears the dynlib objects
void close_ops() {
  for (int op = 0; op < MAX_OPS; ++op) {
    dlclose(LIB[op]);
  }
}

// Applies the specified operation to an input
// Requires a shared object file with a name equivalent to the decimal
// representation of op to be loaded on the current directory
int compute(int op, int x) {
  if (!OP[op]) {
    load_op(op);
  }
  return OP[op](x);
}

int main() {
  int opcode;
  int number;

  printf("Enter the opcode: ");
  scanf("%d", &opcode);

  printf("Enter the number: ");
  scanf("%d", &number);

  printf("Result: %d\n", compute(opcode, number));

  return 0;
}
```

All the credit to the people who took their time to answer my question here and on #c on Libera.Chat. Thank you!